# BrokenPipeError - SQLAlchemy - Cloud SQL - App Engine Standard

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I have an app on App Engine Standard that uses Cloud SQL (postgres) database. Whenever the app seems to go idle, I get `BrokenPipeError`s, but I can't figure out why.

I am getting the following stack trace from stackdriver:

```
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
at write (/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py:607)
at execute (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pg8000/core.py:1908)
at execute (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pg8000/core.py:860)
at do_execute (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:588)
at _execute_context (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1246)
at reraise (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:153)
at _handle_dbapi_exception (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1478)
at _execute_context (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1250)
at _execute_clauseelement (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1101)
at _execute_on_connection (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:293)
at execute (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:982)
at _execute_and_instances (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3414)
at __iter__ (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3389)
at one_or_none (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3316)
at one (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3347)
at load_on_pk_identity (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py:284)
at _get_impl (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:1116)
at get (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:1004)
at graphql (/srv/app.py:168)
at wrapper (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py:129)
at wrapped_function (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/decorator.py:128)
at dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1935)
at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1949)
at reraise (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39)
at handle_user_exception (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1820)
at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1951)
at wsgi_app (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:2446)
```

The key line seems to be `at graphql (/srv/app.py:168)` which is:

```
user = models.User.query.get(user_uuid) # Flask-SQLAlchemy convenience method
```

It looks like my db connection has gone stale, which is why it fails. It also happens at different entry points on an identical line. I guess my question is -- does App Engine close connections when it spins down/hibernates instances. Seems to me like it should start them back up on re-initialization if so. I can't replicate this locally, so I assume it has something to do with the way the services are configured, either our Cloud SQL instance automatically closes connections or App Engine is doing it? But the documentation around this is sparse and I haven't found any information on it. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: I have the same problem.. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. A first quick fix for me was to go away from the pg8000 driver and just use psycopg2.

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f'postgres+psycopg2://{db_user}:{db_password}@/{db_name}?host=/cloudsql/{db_connection_name}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Broken pipe errors usually happen when attempts are made to write to a socket fully closed on the other side. This might be happening when a client program doesn't wait till all the data from the server is received and simply closes a socket (using close function). Problem is treated extensively on the "B.4.2.8 MySQL server has gone away" documentation page for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html).

Also, I think it would be convenient to review the [MySQL Best practices](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/best-practices#app) puting special attention in the proper application implementation in what concerns MySQL connection handling.